# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API Response Caching

Tags: caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am trying to implement response caching in my web api using the "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCaching" package.

I am using Postman to test the application and validate headers etc.

The correct headers are generated with the specified max-age but postman seems to request the response from the api and not using the cache. The response time does not vary at all and if I debug the controller I can see that it gets hit by the request every time.

Startup class ConfigureServices (along with other stuff):

```
services.AddResponseCaching();
```

Startup class Configure (along with other stuff):

```
 app.UseResponseCaching();

 app.UseMvc();
```

Controller Action:

```
    [HttpGet("{employeeNr}", Name = EmployeeAction)]
    [ResponseCache(Duration = 50)]
    [Produces(typeof(EmployeeDto))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetEmployee(SpecificEmployeeParameters parameters)
    {
        if (!await _employeeRepository.EmployeeExists(parameters.EmployeeNr)) return NotFound();

        if (!_typeHelperService.TypeHasProperties<EmployeeDto>(parameters.Fields))
            return BadRequest();

        var entity = await _employeeRepository.GetEmployee(parameters.EmployeeNr);

        var result = Mapper.Map<EmployeeDto>(entity);
        return Ok(result.ShapeData(parameters.Fields));
    }
```

Response headers from Postman:

```
cache-control →private,max-age=50
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Wed, 30 Aug 2017 11:53:06 GMT
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The code above is alright!
Postman was preventing caching by a setting.

To fix this behaviour go to Postman Settings:

```
General -> Headers -> Send no-cache header -> Set to "OFF"
```

Comment: I've run into this also. Although the RFC requires this behavior for a cache when a browser request has a no-cache/no-store header, it really only makes sense for an intermediary cache like an ISP or CDN. The server shouldn't be forced to re-render if it's the owner of the content & knows it hasn't changed. Here's an extension I wrote which allows you to turn off this default behavior of ASP.Net Core's ResponseCache: github.com/speige/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions