# ASP.NET Core Response Caching Not Working As Expected

Tags: http, asp.net-core, postman

I'm struggling to get response caching in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web API working.

I've added response caching in the middleware:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCaching();
    ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseResponseCaching();
    ...
}
```

Here my action method code:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 30)]
[HttpGet()]
public IActionResult GetLookups()
{
    Lookup lookups = dataRepository.GetContactLookups();
}
```

Here's the postman request and response:
[image]

So, I'm getting the correct **Cache-Control** http header in the response but if I send the response again from postman, it still calls my code in my action method. I expected it to not call my code and use the cached response.

Am I misunderstanding the way that response caching works? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with Postman you have to disable Send-No-Cash header ( no-cache header makes sure you get the freshest response from your server)

[ASP.NET Core 2.0 Web API Response Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45960082/asp-net-core-2-0-web-api-response-caching)

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Will save many headaches. Although the RFC requires this behavior for a cache when a browser request has a no-cache/no-store header, it really only makes sense for an intermediary cache like an ISP or CDN. The server shouldn't be forced to re-render if it's the owner of the content & knows it hasn't changed. Here's an extension I wrote which allows you to turn off this default behavior:  https://github.com/speige/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions
https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.ResponseCaching.Extensions